# How to add/update/delete div dynamically using jquery+php+mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sorting

I have following divs listed in main div "testList"

```
<div id="testList">
    <div id="87_1">Test 1</div>
    <div id="88_2">Test 2</div>
    <div id="90_3">Test 3</div>
    <div id="101_4">Test 4</div>
    <div id="110_5">Test 5</div>
</div>
```

where `id` in inner div called `87_1`, `88_2` represents `id` of DB entry and order entry respectively. Where `87` represents `id` and `1` represents `orderNum` fields in DB Table.

Now when user clicks on "add item" button and when `<div id="88_2">Test 2</div>` is selected then adding new test item `<div id="120_3">Test 6</div>` should be added just under `<div id="88_2">Test 2</div>` so after adding new `Test 6` should be looked like

```
<div id="testList">
    <div id="87_1">Test 1</div>
    <div id="88_2">Test 2</div>
    <div id="120_3">Test 6</div>
    <div id="90_4">Test 3</div>
    <div id="101_5">Test 4</div>
    <div id="110_6">Test 5</div>
</div>
```

so it means other div elements order part will be changed. When inserting in DB Table I am managing adding new element with specified order and then updating all following elements with new order.

But how to manage in front using jQuery. Because refreshing entire "testList" div would be slow.

Any help would be heartly appreciated.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/ is what you want. scan the child nodes of `#testList`, find the one BEFORE where you want to insert the new node, then `.insertAfter()`

Comment: Thanks @MarcB. But I would like to reorder the or update `ids` of `div` after insertion. I have actually shown the final output but when first inserted then other elements' order will be duplicated. I am updating question though.